# git (windows): How to ignore lines starting with x on rescan

Tags: windows, git, sed, filter, ignore

I have a date stamp line generated in my cs files which obviously let Git think the file changed and flag them for Unstaged changes. I would like Git to ignore these lines.

1) I have added the filter reference line to the attribute file:
`*.cs filter=CGGenDateStamp`

2) And have started adding the filter tag lines to the config file.

```
[filter="CGGenDateStamp"]
clean=sed 's/Generated by CG = .*/Generated by CG = false'
smudge=sed 's/Generated by CG = .*/Generated by CG = true'
```

But I have no idea how to write the RExp.

The LOC I want to ignore (or replace with dummy string) in my cs files is:

```
// Generated by CG on 19-06-2016 14:04
```

The only change in this LOC between files are the date and time values.

Does anybody know how to write the clean and smudge portion for my above LOC?